# Load dynamic splitpane in javafx using fxml files

Tags: dynamic, javafx, loading, fxml, splitpane

I have a main jfx class having splitpane.
On the lefthand side, I have a treeview and right side is blank. This is created using main fxml file. Now the requirement is the right hand side of splitpane should be loaded based on event of the treeitem on the lefthandside of the pane. Of course the righthandside should display contents of the new fxml file.

Can anybody provide a small example in order to achieve this?

Comment: First try to load fxml file and set it as right side of splitpane, then get its controller class and set the item that is selected from treeview on the left side. If you will stuck somewhere post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Uluk. I was loading the FXML File but I had a small glitch in my code. I found that I had not mapped it against the right side of the splitpane, infact had not mapped it at all. Now my code is working fine. Many thanks for the critical HINT that was required to fix it.